# how can i use flat buffer for polygon?

Tags: arcgis-9.3, buffer

I'd like to create flat buffer in a polygon shapefile. I try to use buffer tool in ArcGIS 9.3, but I couldn't select the "flat" option in the endtype combo-box because the input feature is polygon. How can I select a flat buffer in buffer tool?

Comment: Remember that the "flat" option is only available at the mighty ArcINFO license level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i have understood what you meant by flat buffer on polygon, you could apply these steps :

- feature to polyline.
- [Split at vertices](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=split_line_at_vertices_%28data_management%29)
- buffer with flat enabled
- Append the original polygon to the buffer_result
- dissolve on a commun value, if there's not a commun value, add a field to make commun value

Answer (score 0):

This is an update to this question if you are using ArcGIS Desktop >= 10.6 or Pro >=2.8.

The Graphic Buffer tool in the Analysis>Proximity toolbox does that with many other fine tuning options:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/graphic-buffer.htm